# When does an adjective end in hu1 (乎)?

Tags: characters, adjectives

When does an adjective end in hu1 (乎)? To paraphrase, what do adjectives ending in 乎 have in common?

Comment: **现代汉语词典**  ：乎（２）形容词或副词后缀：巍巍～｜郁郁～｜迥乎不问｜确乎重要。 **应用汉语词典**  ：（７）（助）用在形容词或副词之后表示 
 **停顿或强调**  ：神～其技｜焕～其有文章｜确～如此｜庶几～两不含胡｜于是～学习小组就成立了
 
  **bkrs**  ：〈后缀〉 (1) 单用或叠用在单音或叠音的形容词后面。 如: 许多新事物, 确乎到处可见; 我心里热乎乎的; 他胖乎乎的 (2) 用在动词或副词后面, 构成新的动词或副词。 如: 他对这点事却不在乎; 几乎人人都称赞他 (3) 用在形容词后面, 单独不能翻译 宜乎众矣。 --宋·周敦颐《爱莲说》 洸洸乎干城之具。 --明·刘基《卖柑者言》 昂昂乎庙堂之器。 巍巍乎可畏。 赫赫乎可象。 Also note 乎乎:心里感到温暧; 心里热乎乎的 胖乎乎的脸蛋, 肉乎乎的脸颊 plump：胖乎乎的小手， 你别傻乎乎的，事情没有那么简单。 Don’t be naive. The matter is not so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

乎 usually does not form adjectives, but adverbs, that is modified verbs or adjectives. 胖 is an adjective, 胖乎乎 is an adverb, or a modified adjective, adding an enhancing element, or an injection if you will: fat to a great extent; 急乎乎: in an extreme hurry.

乎 has other uses, but with regard to your question, it is an enhancing modifier.

Answer (score 1):

For second question.
Almost all the adjectives. But this is an old Chinese usage, it strengthens adjectives' effects.
Now we use it in the spoken language, which adjectives could use it depends on custom.

Comment: Ok, so it strengthens the effect of the adjective. Interesting, I was not aware of this.